# Excel Scatter Graph - X (Performance) & Y (Volatility)

Tags: excel, graph, scatter-plot

looking for a bit of assistance

I want a scatter graph with the X axix showing performance of an investment fund comparative to the Y axis which will have a volatility value.

Thus far the scatter graph takes the data and separates the two values out, I want the scatter plot to have incorporated both figures.

I have included an image showing, if someone could point out where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance

[ScatterGraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STeny.png)

Answer (score 0):

When inserting your chart, make sure you choose the second option:

[image]